# Change letter case in jEditable input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, jeditable, capitalization

I would like to change case (all caps or capitalize first letter of sentence) when editing field in place with [jEditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/) plugin. My code looks similar to this:

```
$(".edit").editable("some/url/", {
    type   : 'text',
    submitdata: { _method: "put" },
    select : true,
    event  : "dblclick",
    submit : 'OK',
    cancel : 'cancel',
    id   : 'edititem',
    name : 'newvalue'
});
```

I would like to add `onkeyup` function to my input fields, something like `onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase()"` but I'm really not sure how to do that...
Maybe there is some other way to achieve this??

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're already using jQuery, try this:

```
$('input').bind('keyup', function() {
    $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
});
```

[Works like a charm JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K6M4M/)

Comment: ok, i see... nice :) however, this won't work with jEditable... when i click on my `edit` div, input field which shows up just wont obey `toUpperCase()` function :)

Comment: that's because you need to bind the keyup function after the input has been dynamically created. I'm still working on a solution. a callback from jeditable would be nice here.

Answer (score 1):

rsplak has it basically right. you just need one more bit of magic to make it work.

```
$(".edit").editable("some/url/", {
    type   : 'text',
    submitdata: { _method: "put" },
    select : true,
    event  : "dblclick",
    submit : 'OK',
    cancel : 'cancel',
    id   : 'edititem',
    name : 'newvalue'
});

$(".edit").dblclick(function() {
    $('input').bind('keyup', function() {
        $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
    });
});
```

That will get you there.